# StoreKit 2: Custom purchase option isn't recorded

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

The StoreKit 2 function for purchasing a product takes an array of options. One option is for setting an app account id, and another is for setting a custom key/value pair.

Setting the app account id seems to work great in that the id can be seen in the transaction after making the purchase, and is persisted indefinitely. Setting a custom key/value pair, however, doesn't seem to do anything. The key/value pair doesn't seem to appear anywhere in the transaction or purchase at any time, even immediately after `purchase()` is called.

The documentation on `PurchaseOptions` is very limited, and there doesn't seem to be any explanation as to why this happens. All I've found is [this thread from 2 years ago](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/690384) where an Apple engineer states that purchase options are *"not necessarily returned in the Transaction for the purchase"*. Does this mean that they are sometimes included? And if so, how can I guarantee that? Has anyone found any solutions, or even an answer as to why Apple would include a feature that works like this?

Docs:

- [func purchase(options: Set<Product.PurchaseOption> = []) async throws -> Product.PurchaseResult](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/product/3791971-purchase)
- [static func appAccountToken(_ token: UUID) -> Product.PurchaseOption](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/product/purchaseoption/3749440-appaccounttoken)
- [static func custom(key: String, value: Data) -> Product.PurchaseOption](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/product/purchaseoption/3875421-custom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/product/purchaseoption/3875422-custom#discussion) states:

> Custom purchase options don’t have any effect and are reserved for future use.

So, it looks like the behaviour you are seeing is expected.

Comment: Wow, what a bummer. Thanks for pointing that out in the docs though, I missed that line.